# kinit command error, while generating a TGT- SPNEGO

Tags: single-sign-on, kerberos, spnego

I got error 6 client not found in kerberos database error while running kinit command.

Can you help me with the possibilies of this error?

We are implementing SSO on our application using SPNEGO.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Needs much more details.  Kerberos requires proper SPNs in conjunction with proper DNS configuration in order to work.  Share your /etc/krb5.conf file and share your keytab creation syntax, the problem will likely be spotted in one or both of those two places.  Share both of those by editing your question rather than placing in the comments.

Comment: To begin with: what is the _full_ principal name in the KDC? What is the principal name you are feeding to `kinit`? What did you set in `/etc/krb5.conf` for default KDC, for connection params to the KDC your principal belongs to, etc

Comment: @T-Heron and Samson Sorry for the late response. Thank you for your reverting back. The issue is with Service account having multiple SPN's wherein our Shell company AD server will allow one SPN for a service account. We have removed the duplicate SPN and Kerberos authentication is working.

Comment: Please make your comment as an answer and self-accept it, so that it sign posts it to others a solution was implemented.